# How do I resolve active directory connection errors when using dcpromo?

Tags: active-directory

When attempting to promote a secondary server to an existing active directory forest I receive the following error message and can no longer continue.

> Failed to examine the active directory forest.
>   Value ridMasterDSA.partentDN not found

What can cause this and what can be done to fix it?

Both servers are 2008 running on x64 and can see each other on the network via their names.
FYI: The firewall is turned off on both machines so there should be no issue there.  Also the server that i'm adding is already a part of the domain.  One server is already a domain controller but I want to add a second to it.

Comment: Make certain both servers are pointing at the same AD DNS server.  Also, in your Q: did you mean parentDN or partentDN. And finally, try running DCDiag to look for clues.  Sounds like an issue with roles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your existing DC doesn't hold the RID Master role. You can query for role holders by running `netdom query fsmo`. If you get any unexpected results, you'll have to seize any missing roles.

Did you ever have another DC that died and was improperly removed from the domain?

Comment: yes I did.  I removed al the entries out of the dns domain groups after that happened.

Comment: That's not enough. You're going to have to seize the FSMO roles that the dead DC had. There are plenty of questions here and articles on technet for how to do this.

Comment: This is also a good resource http://www.petri.co.il/seizing_fsmo_roles.htm

Comment: that was really insightful.  when I ran that it told me that I have a role owner in a deleted dc.

Comment: you have no idea how little good info there is on this out ther.  The stack site outperform once more.